# How to compile Boost with an older std of C++? (C++03 in particular)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, c++03

I am working in a project dependent of Boost (http://kratos-wiki.cimne.upc.edu/index.php/Main_Page), this project currently only supports C++03. With the last update of gcc++ (v.5) the C++11 has become the default std, technically I solved the problem modifying the CXX_FLAGS adding:

> -std=c++03

The problem comes with the Boost library, which I am not able to compile with the C++03 std (I think, I don't know how to check with which std I have compiled). I tried employing the following command to compile Boost:

> ./b2 install stage --with-python --with-serialization cxxflags="-std=c++03"

I have tried too modify the Jamroot file, adding the following lines:

> ```
>   <toolset>gcc:<cxxflags>-std=gnu++03
>   <toolset>clang:<cxxflags>-std=c++03
> ```

But the problem persist, when I compile the whole project I obtain the following kind of warning (several times):

> /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/detail/template_arity_spec.hpp:13:84: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated
>    # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated")

That's why I suspect that my changes do not take effect.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with Boost, google it.

Comment: I already did, probably I didn't do it the right way.

Comment: See http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/264164. As those are only warnings you could probably continue your work and wait for a fix. Alternatively, you could test an older boost version if you want.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can safely ignore those warnings for now.  I am compiling boost 1_60_0 with gcc 5.2.1 and std=c++11, and I get the same warnings.  There is a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11860) on it, but meanwhile it hasn't caused me any problems at this time.  I commented out the two [#pragma warning] lines in the boost code, so I don't get a lot of distracting output in my build:

boost/type_traits/detail/template_arity_spec.hpp line 13:

```
// noisy: # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated")
```

boost/type_traits/detail/bool_trait_def.hpp line 18:

```
// noisy: # pragma message ("NOTE: Use of this header (bool_trait_def.hpp) is deprecated")
```

**UPDATE** The problem still exists in boost 1.61.0.  I used the same exact fix again.

Comment: Same here. This can be ignored for now. Thanks for the link to the ticket.

Comment: I can't believe it, but it appears that they didn't fix this in 1.61.0.  Oh well, same exact code, same exact fix still works.