# Disable g++ pragma message

Tags: c++

I'm compiling a C++ project with `gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)`.

The project uses the cpp_netlib library which includes boost spirit.

It outputs a lot of `# pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (some_file.hpp) is deprecated")`.

Is there any way to get rid of this ?

I'm aware there is a lot of questions about it on SO but I'm not sure any of them really gives a viable solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried  `-ftrack-macro-expansion=0` and `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret` ?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed :/

Comment: boost give so much pragma comment, to reduce you can read it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480467/how-to-compile-boost-with-an-older-std-of-c-c03-in-particular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there is absolutely no way to disable a #pragma message.

There is a boost ticket about this annoying use of the pragma.

Long story short, I removed them from the headers.

`find $ROOT_DEPS_BUILD_PATH/boost/include -type f -exec sed -i '/pragma.*deprecated/d' {} \;`