# Does boost 1.71.0 support C++03?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

I cannot find anywhere that says it doesn't, but I cannot even install boost 1.71.0 without a C++11 compiler because Boost.Build uses C++11.

If it is supported, are there build instructions for C++03?  If it is not, what is the last boost version that is?

I realize that C++03 is outdated, and I would upgrade if I could, but I'm stuck for this project.

Comment: See __Compilers Tested__ https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_71_0.html  looks like the earliest is `C++0x` ie just pre C++11

Comment: I am using gcc 4.4.7, which is which they say they are using.  I'm having trouble in running bootstrap.sh in the first stage of the build.  It hardcodes -std=c++11 when it detects the gcc toolchain.  If I hack at their scripts to replace it with -std=c++0x I get errors trying to compile b2.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480467/560648

Comment: If you're struggling I think you should raise a bug with Boost - it seems like this is still intended to work

Comment: It seems that Boost is supposed to work with gcc 4.4.7, but Boost.Build only works with 4.7 and up.  I filed an issue with Boost.